# DateTime2 not supported anymore?

Tags: .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

**FINAL EDIT / TLDR**:

Well indeed the issue was not related to EF but **SQL Server**: I had 3 versions running on this particular machine: **2005** (don't know from where!), **2008** and **2012**.

For an unknown reason the **2005** version was used as the default.

So I've uninstalled it and reinstalled the 2012 version forcing the correct default name to be used (**"SQLEXPRESS"**).

Since then I can force a `DateTime` to be mapped to a `DateTime2` without any issue.

---

I've seen some code samples using:

```
[Column(TypeName = "DateTime2")]
```

to map a .Net `DateTime` to **SQL Server** `DateTime2`.

But with the latest `EF 6.1.1` this seems broken.

I've debugged the source code and found that indeed `DateTime2` is not in the list of SQL Server supported types!

Here is a simple repro:

```
class BrokenDateTime2
{
    public long Id { get; set; }

    [Column(TypeName = "DateTime2")]
    public DateTime DateTime2 { get; set; }
}

class Context : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<BrokenDateTime2> BrokenDateTime2 { get; set; }
}

...

using (Context context = new Context())
{
    context.Database.Initialize(true);
}
```

What am I missing?

EDIT: more code

It explodes in:

```
public static PrimitiveType GetStoreTypeFromName(this DbProviderManifest providerManifest, string name)
{
    ...
    return providerManifest.GetStoreTypes()
                           .Single(p => string.Equals(p.Name, name, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase));
}
```

And indeed when I watch `providerManifest.GetStoreTypes()` I don't see any which would match `DateTime2`.

The exception is:

```
InvalidOperationException: Sequence contains no matching element
```

Comment: I think this should be posted on the codeplex page under issues, since you have already debuged the source code and conformed it, so SO users may only tell you "Yes you are correct". http://entityframework.codeplex.com/workitem/list/advanced

Comment: I see many occurrences of "datetime2" in the current code. Can't believe it's been away for a while. When I try 6.1.1 it creates DateTime2 columns alright. Where exactly did you look?

Comment: @RandRandom You may be right but I'm not sure this is a bug so I first present it to the wisdom of the SO community. :) If this is a confirmed issue then I'll post a bug report on the EF team bug tracking system you pointed to.

Comment: What exactly breaks? If you let us know, it may be easier to assist

Comment: @GertArnold Ahah glad to see the issue is only on my side, I'll update with more code.

Comment: I think you didn't look in the  EntityFramework.SqlServer library which exists since v.6.

Comment: @GertArnold `EntityFramework.SqlServer` is referenced in my project, it is automatically added when I install the "EntityFramework" NuGet package. Should I do something special with it?

Comment: Datetime2 is fully supported, and mentioned in the source. Looks like EF thinks you are connecting to SQL Server 2005 or earlier

Comment: @ErikEJ : interesting, I'm using SQL Server 2012 and everything else works perfectly well.

Comment: Works fine for me. what does this line of code return in the GetStoreTypeFromName method. `providerManifest.GetType().GetProperty("SqlVersion", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance).GetValue(providerManifest)`?

Comment: I'm using SQL 2012 and also SQL Azure, all date properties across app are declared as [Column(TypeName = "datetime2")]. Working well.

Comment: @ErikEJ well guessed this was the issue. :) Thanks

Comment: Please move your "final edit" to an answer.  (You can answer your own question.)

Comment: I was waiting for Erik to post it. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Datetime2 is fully suported by Entity Framework if you run SQL Server 2008 and later, but not with SQL Server 2005!